# How to configure JBoss 7.1.1 with hibernate 4.1 and Envers 4.1?

Tags: hibernate, jboss, hibernate-envers

I'm having a problem in my project. We are using JBoss7.1.1 and we want to use envers in version 4.1. Envers in version 4.1 requires Hibernate in version 4.1. Unfortunately jboss 7.1.1 contains older hibernate and Envers modules.

I have 2 options:

Change modules in JBoss (put there new envers & hibernate). The problem is every jboss that will run this application will have to be "tuned" for that project (a bit painfull).

Or:

Exclude JBoss modules and use libs from WEB-INF/lib inside war. 
I excluded the modules using:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment>
        <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies     -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.hibernate"/>
            <module name="org.hibernate.envers"/>
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I've changed dependencies in maven from provided to compile and it should work, right?

But now I'm getting this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface org.hibernate.annotations.Columns is not visible from class loader
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass(Proxy.java:353) [classes.jar:1.6.0_35]
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.annotationfactory.AnnotationFactory.create(AnnotationFactory.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAOverridenAnnotationReader.buildColumns(JPAOverridenAnnotationReader.java:1383)
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend not to use different versions of Hibernate for your app.

I suggest you download hibernate 4.1.3 and other relevant ones, replace the jars & update module.xml with correct jars. We use 7.1.1 with Hibernate 4.1.3 Core and Envers.

Replacing the Envers module.xml

```
  <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.hibernate.envers">
    <resources>
      <resource-root path="hibernate-envers-4.1.3.Final.jar"/>
      <!-- Insert resources here -->
    </resources>

  <dependencies>
    <module name="org.hibernate"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
    <module name="org.dom4j"/>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    <module name="org.hibernate.commons-annotations"/>
    <module name="org.javassist"/>
   </dependencies>
 </module>

Change also org/hibernate/main/ (we use hibernate core 4.1.3.Final)
Change org/hibernate/validator/main ( we use hibernate validator-4.2.0.Final)
Change org/hibernate/commons-annotations (we use 4.0.1 Final)
```

That should be it.. Let me know if any dependency issues arise..

-Maddy